# How do I intercept the clicked option?

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-select, bootstrap-select

I'm developing a web application using Angular 6. I'm using in this project the **bootstrap-select** library to implement dynamic combo boxes. I do not know the library well, but 
I would need to have a method that intercepts a user click on an option element. For example, in this code (that uses the library):

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker"
        data-live-search="true"
>
<option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value" 
[selected]="selectedOption == option">{{option.label}}</option>
</select>
```

I would like that a user, when he clicks on the option menu item, make start the method that intercepts the name of the current `<option>`.
the classic `(click)="method(currentOption)"` event doesn't working on the `<option>` elements. How can I get it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `(change)="yourMethod()"` along with an `[(ngModel)]="selectedOption"`. You'll have to define a property named `selectedOption` on your Component Class:

```
<select 
  class="form-control selectpicker"
  data-live-search="true"
  (change)="onChange($event)"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
  <option 
    *ngFor="let option of options" 
    [value]="option.value" 
    [selected]="selectedOption == option">
    {{option.label}}
  </option>
</select>
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9wt9cv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Ok. But how do I pass data related to the specific object in the method?

Comment: You can simply bind it to the `ngModel` directive. I've updated the answer along with a Sample StackBlitz. :)

Comment: @claudioz, did that answer your question?